# How do you test network speed without an app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, wifi, internet

The usual Internet speed test is written in Flash. Is there an HTML one that works with iPad and iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISPGeeks.com has a non-flash java based bandwidth tester. It pretty accurately measured the speed of my iPad on my home connection, as compared to similar tests on the usual Flash-based sites.

Comment: It worked: http://www.ispgeeks.com/wild/modules.php?name=Bandwidth_Meter_DSL . Click go.

Answer (score 7):

SpeedTest.net has an iPad/iPhone/iPod app.

Comment: There is an app for that ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try http://speedof.me

It use **html5** and works without flash.

You can also see your bandwidth graph which is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

[dslreports.com](http://www.dslreports.com/) is my go-to resource for carrier/network info and diagnostics. Free membership, no spam, genuine user generated content, reviews, and support all are part.  The "tools" section is very robust.